# overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible

Tags: css

I am building a carousel and I want the container to have overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible.When the items are hovered
a transform: scale() is applied and I want them to overflow from the container but only on the y axis.

I tried to set the container to overflow-x: hidden and the child to overflow-y: visible but that didn't work.

```css
:root {
  --item-margin: 5px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  margin-top: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-20% - 5px);
  transition: .5s ease all;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ED4956;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 2%;
  top: 50%;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: 98%;
  top: 50%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4rem;
  transition: .4s ease transform;
}

.child {
  margin-right: var(--item-margin);
}

.child:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.child1 {
  background: green;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.child4 {
  background: navy;
}

.child5 {
  background: red;
}

.child6 {
  background: pink;
}

.child7 {
  background: grey;
}

.child8 {
  background: brown;
}

.child9 {
  background: #ff80ed;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .child {
    width: calc(25% - var(--item-margin));
  }
  .wrapper {
    left: -25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child child1">1</div>
    <div class="child child2">2</div>
    <div class="child child3">3</div>
    <div class="child child4">4</div>
    <div class="child child5">5</div>
    <div class="child child6">6</div>
    <div class="child child7">7</div>
    <div class="child child8">8</div>
    <div class="child child9">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-arrow"> &larr; </div>
  <div class="right-arrow"> &rarr; </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to give the `.container` a height, for example: `100vh`.

---

Because the tops of the children are cut off i recommend to use `padding-top: 60px` instead of `margin-top: 60px`.

Because of the changed height the arrows are wrong positioned. To adjust this  i used a different `top` value: half of the childrens height plus the containers padding-top (125px + 60px).

Because the `.wrapper` doesn't need `position: relative` in this example i removed it. Maybe in your project it is necessary for the arrow function(s)...

**Working example:** (*watch it in "Full page" mode to see it without scrollbars*)

```css
:root {
  --item-margin: 5px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  left: calc(-20% - 5px);
  transition: .5s ease all;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ED4956;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 185px;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 2%;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: 98%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4rem;
  transition: .4s ease transform;
}

.child {
  margin-right: var(--item-margin);
}

.child:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.child1 {
  background: green;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.child4 {
  background: navy;
}

.child5 {
  background: red;
}

.child6 {
  background: pink;
}

.child7 {
  background: grey;
}

.child8 {
  background: brown;
}

.child9 {
  background: #ff80ed;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .child {
    width: calc(25% - var(--item-margin));
  }
  .wrapper {
    left: -25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child child1">1</div>
    <div class="child child2">2</div>
    <div class="child child3">3</div>
    <div class="child child4">4</div>
    <div class="child child5">5</div>
    <div class="child child6">6</div>
    <div class="child child7">7</div>
    <div class="child child8">8</div>
    <div class="child child9">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-arrow"> &larr; </div>
  <div class="right-arrow"> &rarr; </div>
</div>
```

---

Because the arrows are still cut of you could add an extra container (here `.parent`) and add `height`, `padding-top` and `overflow-x` to it (instead of to the container).

**Working example:** (*watch in "Full page" mode to see it without scrollbars*)

```css
:root {
  --item-margin: 5px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  left: calc(-20% - 5px);
  transition: .5s ease all;
  overflow: visible;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ED4956;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 185px;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 2%;
}

.right-arrow {
  left: 98%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4rem;
  transition: .4s ease transform;
}

.child {
  margin-right: var(--item-margin);
}

.child:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.child1 {
  background: green;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.child4 {
  background: navy;
}

.child5 {
  background: red;
}

.child6 {
  background: pink;
}

.child7 {
  background: grey;
}

.child8 {
  background: brown;
}

.child9 {
  background: #ff80ed;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .child {
    width: calc(25% - var(--item-margin));
  }
  .wrapper {
    left: -25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="child child1">1</div>
      <div class="child child2">2</div>
      <div class="child child3">3</div>
      <div class="child child4">4</div>
      <div class="child child5">5</div>
      <div class="child child6">6</div>
      <div class="child child7">7</div>
      <div class="child child8">8</div>
      <div class="child child9">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-arrow"> &larr; </div>
  <div class="right-arrow"> &rarr; </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just changed the margin-top: 60px with padding: 60px 0 without wrapping them in another div and it works like I wanted.Thank you!It didn't work because the top was cropped when the margin top was applied.

Comment: Oh, that is far easier! Thanks for the feedback. Because it did flicker a bit i changed it to `padding: 70px 0;` and the flickering disappeared...